# How to get coordinates from getCurrentPosition()

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, gps, maps

I wanted to get the coordinates from `getCurrentPosition()` method, so that it can be used in some another method, but I am not able to do it.

This is my HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

This is my JavaScript code

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
  var a = position.coords.latitude;
  var b = position.coords.longitude;

  pos = {a, b}
  console.log(pos);
}
getLocation();
```

I want to access the `pos` variable somehow from the `showPosition()` method. Is there any way I can do it? Or if I cannot, is there any alternative to this method, which can solve my problem? Please help me.

Comment: What is the problem? What is the error?

Comment: @Pop-A-Stash though console.log() displays the array pos but i want to return that pos array so that it can be used somwhere else in the code

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply define `pos` in the global scope, and it will be accessible wherever you need it. You also had an issue with the way you were defining `pos` inside of `showPosition`

```
var x = document.getElementById("map");
var pos;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {


    var a = position.coords.latitude;
    var b = position.coords.longitude;

    pos = [
        a,
        b
    ];

    console.log(pos);

}
getLocation();
```

Comment: by the changes you suggested, console.log(pos) successfully executes within the scope of showPosition() method but fails to execute outside the scope even though the pos is globally declared

Comment: What scope are you talking about? You haven't given an example of how you plan to use the `pos` variable?

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` does not require 2 arguments in modern browsers; it only requires the 1 callback function. Please also note that it is an asynchronous function, so any extra logic must be called within the callback. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition